# Dx trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class"

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I'm trying to use StaX API in my app but it gives me error:

> Dx trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class"

I use Eclipse. I checked different topic related to this error but none of them actualy gives an answer which may work for me. I was deleting all unnecesary libs from project, cleaning and then addind Stax. I don't have any duplicated libraries.

From what I found it doesn't allow me to add javax classes and I can't avoid using them. Can you tell me how exactly can I add external jar containing javax classes and avoid such error?

Comment: were you able to solve this error?

Comment: I have moved to Android Studio and problem didn't appear there, so no solution, rather workaround.